# Coupling factor and Leakage inductance/magnetizing inductance

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

I have so trouble to understand how the leakage/magnetizing inductance is defined in function of the coupling factor. Here is the first definition that I found. It mentions that the secondary is open circuited.

[image]

"It therefore". That's not explicite to me ... If someone can show me how they obtain the coupling factor. Or inversely base on the coupling factor how they can say the leakage/magnetizing inductance is function of the coupling factor.

I understand that it depends on the coupling factor and the formula makes sense to me but I m not able to demonstrate it...

Here is a second definition but this time, the secondary is short circuited. If I do not do mistakes when the secondary is short circuited, the primary inductance is equal to the leakage inductance.

[image]

The source is the following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_inductance.

Also here is the definition from LTspice :

[image]

Thank you very much and have a nice day :)

Comment: In a 2-winding transformer, when you short the secondary, what you "see" in the primary side is \$l_{l1}\$ in series with \$L_m\$ paralleled with \$l_{l2}\$ scaled by the turns ratio squared. \$l_{l1}\$ and \$l_{l2}\$ are the respective primary and secondary leakage terms while \$L_m\$ refers to the magnetizing inductance.

Comment: [This](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/inductor/mutual-inductance.html) should help.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. I have some troubles Verbal Kint to understand what you say. Considering a simpler case, i.e the secondary leakage inductance is null. So the voltage at the secondary is equal to 0V, which implies that the voltage across the magnetizing inductance is 0 V. So it means according to the faraday's Law, there is no magnetic flux variation in function of the time and by integrating there is no flux at all if at t=0 there were no flux at the beginning. So there is no current flowing through the inductance according to Ampere's theorem.

Comment: In other words there is no magnetizing inductance as there is no magnetic field produced. Did I do a mistake ?

Comment: If the secondary leakage inductance is zero (null?) then the secondary voltage is still present @Jess - everything you say that follows is therefore misled.

Comment: Do you understand or have seen the equivalent circuit of a transformer?

Comment: My comment pertained to a model where the two leakage terms are present. But it is true that for the practical case, the second term is often neglected and when the sec. side is shorted, yes, you consider your measurement result as the primary-side leakage term.

Comment: Ok ! Thank you for this :) I will try to consider your case :)